# Business Rule Composer (Not Responding)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have BizTalk 2013r2 Dev VM with CU5 installed, apart from the this problem - the VM works great, I have several BizTalk apps deployed locally and all process ok.

When trying to load the Business Rule Composer, it displays but is unresponsive. The title bar reads Microsoft Business Rule Composer (Not Responding). At the foot of the page, in the status bar, there is the message "Loading...".

When I try to apply the CU6 update I get the following (see the Not Responding) in the title bar:

[image]

I have checked that all the usual suspect windows services are running, MSDTC, Sql Browser, SQl Server etc.

Any ideas what could be causing this? There are no clues in the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a able to fix this by running the BizTalk install MSI from the DVD image and selecting "Repair BizTalk"